# Drag and Drop Deployment Cannnot find DLL

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

After I loaded a new reference to my project, I can no longer run my program on another pc without installing it. I attached an image of the exception message.  If anybody can help I would really appreciate it!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Check the manifest file to make sure
   the filename is correct.
2. Copy the code into your own executable and
   don't use a DLL.
3. Turn Copy Local property to false.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a difference in the MS SQL Installation between the two PC's.

The Dll that is missing is part of MS SQL, therefore either SQL Server is missing completely from the second PC, or there are some options that were not installed on the second PC.

Comment: Its connecting to a remote server and neither of the pcs have sql installed on them.

Comment: Does one of them have SQL Server Client tools installed?

Comment: When you added the new reference, where did you add it from?

Comment: http://devpinoy.org/blogs/keithrull/archive/2006/06/08/Programmatically-List-All-SQL-Servers-And-Their-Databases-Using-SMO-.aspx

I got it from that website then grabbed the dll from his bin folder

Comment: OK. The naming of the dll is confusing since it looks like a Microsoft dll. But if it is generated from that project, you have to mark the reference with copy local = true, when you copy it to the other machine make sure that you also have the dll in your error message.

Comment: I thought of the same thing, so I did set the copy local = true, but that still didn't fix it.  Do you think there is a specific way to add this particular reference?